# Why I'm getting WA in LAPIN problem of codechef?

Tags: python

*Hey guyz, In the LAPIN problem of codechef my code is passing all the testcases but still I am getting WA. I cant find the error in my code, plz help me.....[:(*

**HEREZ THE QUESTION**

Lapindrome is defined as a string which when split in the middle, gives two halves having the same characters and same frequency of each character. If there are odd number of characters in the string, we ignore the middle character and check for lapindrome.

First line of input contains a single integer T, the number of test cases.
Each test is a single line containing a string S composed of only lowercase English alphabet.

**MY CODE**

```
times = int(input())
for num in range(times):
    n = input()
    n = str(n)
    if len(n) == 1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        if len(n) % 2 == 0:
            list2 = []
            list3 = []    
            for i in range(int(len(n)/2)):
                list2.append(n[i])
                list3.append(n[int(len(n)/2)+i])
            if sorted(list2)==sorted(list3):
                print('YES')
            else:
                print('NO')

        else:
            char = str(n)[len(n)//2]
            string_list = str(n).split(char)
            if sorted(string_list[0]) == sorted(string_list[1]):
                print('YES')
            else:
                print('NO')
```

Comment: if you explain the LAPIN problem or post a link, it would be easier to help you

Comment: Other thing, if you find a data set that doesn't work for your code (a lot of times with tiny data sets you can find one), finding a bug also will be easier

Comment: I think the problem may be here: `str(n).split(char)` what if the character in the middle occurs in several places, it splits the string in several piezes, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

with this logic using `string_list = str(n).split(char)` is giving u wrong answer for odd lenght string suppose

```
n = 'aaaaa'
char_ = 'a' # middle character
sorted_list= n.split('a')
# ['', '', '', '', '']
```

so in this case it is creating 5 sublist , also consider when the middle element frequency is more than 1, than it will unpack into more than 2 sublist and not equal

so your code should be

`string_list = [n[:len(n)//2], n[len(n)//2+1:]]`

a proper way to split string from middle into a list having 2 elements

also `range(int(len(n)/2))` should be `range(int(len(n)//2))`

and `range(int(len(n)/2)+i)` should be `range(int(len(n)//2)+1)` ,use `int` division not `float` division in `range`

```
times = int(input())
for num in range(times):
    n = input()
    n = str(n)
    if len(n) == 1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        if len(n) % 2 == 0:
            list2 = []
            list3 = []    
            for i in range(int(len(n)//2)):
                list2.append(n[i])
                list3.append(n[int(len(n)//2)+i])
            if sorted(list2)==sorted(list3):
                print('YES')
            else:
                print('NO')

        else:

            string_list = [n[:len(n)//2], n[len(n)//2+1:]]
            if sorted(string_list[0]) == sorted(string_list[1]):
                print('YES')
            else:
                print('NO')
```